# How to build the Boost Python for both Python2 and Python3?

Tags: python, python3, c++, boost

I was trying to build the Boost 1.65.1 for both versions of Python I use:

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-python=python2 --with-python=python3
```

However, the first instance of the `--with-python` option has been ignored and I've got only `/usr/local/lib/libboost_python3.*` libraries.

So I've called the `bootstrap` in the *same directory* again with command:

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-python=python2
```

After that I've got both Boost Python libraries - for Python2 and Python3.

I've some doubts about this sequence of steps - the second step might damage results of the first one.

Are there any 100%-reliable ways to build the Boost Python (from sources) for both Python versions?

Comment: Hmmm I don't see step 2 damaging anything so maybe just go with it until something actually breaks. Also not sure if you found this but here is a similar quesiton with a much better answer than I could write https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28830653/build-boost-with-multiple-python-versions